# use php variable inside javascript retuns null

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php
 include('Connection.php');
 $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE c.castName = :q");
 $query->execute(array(':q' => $searchText ));
         while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
       ?>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo urlencode($row['ImdbId']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
           <td><a href="#" id="add">Add to list</a>
        </tr>               
     <?php
         endwhile; 
     ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#add').on('click', function (e) {
        var selectedOpts = "<?php echo $row['movieName']; ?>";
        var obj = {
                  "movie_name":selectedOpts,
                  "movie_info": ""
                  };
        parent.window.opener.addToBasket(selectedOpts);  //addToBasket is a function that add selected movies to the basket. 
  }); 
</script>
```

### My question:

When I click on "add to list" link, it add Nothing to the basket (I mean, the function addToBasket works fine, but the value of "selected" is null..

Could someone kindly let me know how should I use `<?php echo $row['movieName'];` inside my javascript code? I know I have to put it between "", but I think there should be another problem.. (maybe because this row is not known in javascript code, but I have no idea how to fix it..)

I add also this image to clarify the problem:

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP-Javascript. Your `$row` variable is `false` after the `while` loop has ended, as simple as that. You need to store that value somewhere else in the meantime.

Comment: @deceze, Thanks for answer.. but how can I enable user to select the movie and add it to the basket then? (I mean how can I use that row?)

Comment: @mOna I think you need to add your jquery code in $(document).ready(); statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested code, but this should work for you :)

```
<?php
 include('Connection.php');
 $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE c.castName = :q");
 $query->execute(array(':q' => $searchText ));
         while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
       ?>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo urlencode($row['ImdbId']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
           <td><a href="javascript:addmovie('<?php echo $row['movieName']; ?>')" id="add">Add to list</a>
        </tr>               
     <?php
         endwhile; 
     ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addmovie(movieName) {
        var obj = {
                  "movie_name":movieName,
                  "movie_info": ""
                  };
        parent.window.opener.addToBasket(obj);  //addToBasket is a function that add selected movies to the basket. 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. it gives me the error: `selectedOpts is not defined!`

Comment: I replaced selectedOpts with obj and it works fine :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .prev() jquery option, that will return the dom object previous to your '#add td.
in this case the  that olds the movie name, and get the value inside the previous  as selectedOps

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues I can see:

1. You have used id="add" for all the rows(movies) and then attaching click event to the id. Change id="add" to class="add".
2. put the movie name in a data attribute like:

`<td><a href="#" class="add" data-movieName="<?php echo $row['movieName']; ?>">Add to list</a>`

3. Then change the javascript to :

   `<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.add').on('click', function (e) {
           var selectedOpts = $(e).data("movieName");
           var obj = {
                     "movie_name":selectedOpts,
                     "movie_info": ""
                     };
           parent.window.opener.addToBasket(selectedOpts);  //addToBasket is a function that add selected movies to the basket. 
     }); 
   </script>`

This should work.

Comment: Good. All answers look almost the same :D

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is you are using "id" to fetch the value

```
<a href="#" id="add">Add to list</a>
```

and you have used while loop because of which your id is getting duplicated and as we all know "id" of element in js should be unique throughout the page.

There are many solutions available for your problem out of which following is one

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
   ?>
    <tr>
       <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo urlencode($row['ImdbId']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
       <td><a href="#" class="add" lang="<?php echo $row['movieName']; ?>">Add to list</a>
    </tr>               
 <?php
     endwhile; 
 ?>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.add').on('click', function (e) {
    var selectedOpts = $(this).attr('lang');
    var obj = {
              "movie_name":selectedOpts,
              "movie_info": ""
              };
    parent.window.opener.addToBasket(selectedOpts);  //addToBasket is a function that add selected movies to the basket. 
  }); 
</script>
```

Suggession : Avoid direct use of php in javascript code instead try to use hidden () variables.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind answer, I just fixed it:)